# Change label text when height expand of cell of tableView in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, heightforrowatindexpath

I am new in IOS and i am using swift.I want to change the text of label when height of cell expand.Please tell me how to change text when height expand of cell in swift.

import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
    {

```
    var selectedIndex = -1
    var height = 54
    // Data model: These strings will be the data for the table view cells
    let animals: [String] = ["Horse", "Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]
    // cell reuse id (cells that scroll out of view can be reused)
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

    // don't forget to hook this up from the storyboard
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    // number of rows in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 2
    }

    // create a cell for each table view row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell:Cell1 = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell1!
        cell.textLabel?.text = "-"
        return cell
    }

    // method to run when table view cell is tapped

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
         let cell:Cell1 = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell1!
        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
            height = 216

            cell.textLabel?.text = "+"
        }else{
             height = 54
             cell.textLabel?.text = "/"
        }
        return CGFloat(height)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")

        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
            selectedIndex = -1
        }
        else
        {

            selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just change the text in your textfield where you are calling the code to change the cell height yourTextField.text = "required content"

Comment: Please help me by my code which is edited

Comment: I am not able to understand where i change the text

Comment: To sum up your question, do you wish to change the text for a particular index?

Comment: yes, i want to change the text of label of expanded cell of tableview

Comment: the cell which is not expanded is remains the same

Comment: Do you want to expand UITableViewCell height based on content of label inside cell? Or some other scenario? If that is someother scenario means explain clearly for easy understanding

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to dequeue the cell again in your `heightForRowAt` function, I think that's your issue.

so try replace your `heightForRowAt` function with the below code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) 
    if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
    {
        height = 216

        cell.textLabel?.text = "+"
    }else{
         height = 54
         cell.textLabel?.text = "/"
    }
    return CGFloat(height)
}
```